# Does CIVector use row- or column-major order?

Tags: ios, matrix, core-image, homography

I'm trying to create a CIVector containing a matrix of values. Does CIVector use row- or column- major order?

In case, it matters, this matrix represents a homography:

```
let observation: VNImageHomographicAlignmentObservation = ...
// The input uses column-major order, so convert it to row-major 
// for CIVector:
let (col0, col1, col2) = observation.warpTransform.columns
let values: [CGFloat] = [CGFloat(col0.x), CGFloat(col1.x), CGFloat(col2.x),
                        CGFloat(col0.y), CGFloat(col1.y), CGFloat(col2.y),
                        CGFloat(col0.z), CGFloat(col1.z), CGFloat(col2.z)]
let vector = CIVector(values: values, count: values.count)
```

Comment: As far as I know, a `CIVector` contains (1) two-to-whatever dimension needed and is (2) dependent on how it's "consumed" by the filter (or kernel). Usually it's 2-4 dimensions, but in your case it appears to be 9. I guess the real question is how are you using it?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm using it as per the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746563/what-is-com-apple-vis-error-11-when-trying-to-align-two-images-using-vision